# Getting issue while sending nested JSON as request to validate the POST REST API method using Karate framework

Tags: rest, web-api-testing, karate

Please note that i am trying to send the below request and validate the response on POST method using url

`http://uat-ws.*.uk.***.ws/index.php/*/****/validatevoucher`

like below: I am using Karate framework here to automate REST API

```
Scenario: validate voucher

Given url 'http://-..uk../v3//******' 
And header Content-Type = 'application/json' 
And request {json request here}
When method post
Then status 200 



12:17:30.510 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.StepDefs - response time in milliseconds: 579 12:17:30.528 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.StepDefs - FAILED, status code was 400, expected 200

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m [31mexamples/users/WSS.feature:3 [0m# Scenario: validate voucher

1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m) 5 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [32m4 passed[0m) 0m3.516s

com.intuit.karate.KarateException: status code was 400, expected 200 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.handleFailure(StepDefs.java:516) at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.status(StepDefs.java:447) at ✽.Then status 200(examples/users/WSS.feature:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it pretty clear from the error that the request is hitting the server, but the server is responding with a 400.  The Karate test is working fine, but looks like the server was expecting some other JSON or content-type.

My suggestion is take the help of someone who can look at the server logs, and find out why the server is throwing a 400.

Edit: After re-reading your question, I'm guessing you are trying to form a nested JSON. Yes the JSON you attempted to use in the script is wrong.  Can you try this. Since you have hidden a lot of the actual request it is very hard to see the problem. Please get familiar with JSON and how to create nested JSON like in the example below.

```
And request
"""
{ 
  memberId: '******', 
  memberIpAddress: '******', 
  voucherData: { 
    blabla: { 
      voucherNo: '*****', 
      voucherValue: '***', 
      voucherIssueDate': '', 
      voucherExpiryDate: '******' 
    } 
  } 
}
"""
```